# Java Properties object to ContentBody

Tags: java, io, properties-file

I have a `Properties` object. I need to send its content as file over HTTP POST.

The `Properties` class allows me to write to a file, but I'm trying to avoid actually writing to the filesystem, since I already have what I need in memory and just want to send it over the network.

The `MultipartEntityBuilder` class allows me to provide a `ContentBody`. What's the shortest path to convert my `Properties` object to a `ContentBody`?

Answer (score 2):

The below demonstrates how you can write it to a String which you can use to POST. See if it helps.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties prop= new Properties();
    prop.put("aa", "ff");
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    prop.list(new PrintWriter(sw));
    System.out.println(sw.toString());
}
```